# Will the way you make a coil affect magnetic induction?

Tags: electromagnetism

We had an experiment about magnetic induction. We discoved that as the number of coils you make the induced voltage and current increases.

But I'm wondering if I made the coil messy or made the coiling just in one loop, will it affect the induced current and voltage? 
I asked this because I only see one type of coiling in books.It is always the tube-like one.

Also, is a tube considered a coils of wire in magnetic induction?
and, will the cross sectional are of the wire affect magnetic induction?

I hope you understand my question. 
Thanks :)[image]

Answer (score 1):

The coiling has to be systematic to increase the induction effects. If you just bend the wires in random way, most of the induction from one part will cancel induction from the other part. To obtain increase in the induction, the wire parts have to cooperate, and to do that, you need to coil the wire in a neat systematic way.

Comment: but what if you coil it systematically but just making one loop? (making it layered in one circle) and how magnetic induction is affected in a tube?

Comment: It does not matter much whether the wire is in one plane or tube. The spiral decreases the inductance, however. To obtain as great inductance as possible, you should bend the wire to form as large circles as possible.

Answer (score 0):

The dimensions of the individual loops along with the number of loops will affect the $induced$ $E.M.F$

$Faraday's$ $Law$ $of$ $Electromagnetic$ $Induction$,

$\oint \vec{E}.\vec{dl} = -\frac{\mathrm{d} }{\mathrm{d} t}\iint_{ }^{ } \vec{B}.\vec{dA}$

$L.H.S$ of the equation gives us the $induced$ $E.M.F$

Observe the $R.H.S$ of the equation below,

It is clear that the magnetic flux $\iint_{ }^{ } \vec{B}.\vec{dA}$ depends on the area enclosed by the loop. $Flux$ of a property( $\vec{B}$, $\vec{E}$,etc..) tells us how much of that property flows through a given surface( $open$ $or$ $closed$ ). For a uniform $\vec{B}$ in space, a large surface will allow more number of magnetic field lines to go through it when compared to a relatively small surface. This tells us that the $Flux$  associated with the large surface is more when compared to the $Flux$ associated with a relatively small surface. So, greater the $flux$ $change$ greater will be the $induced$ $E.M.F$. Also, greater the number of loops that make up the coil, greater will be the $induced$ $E.M.F$.

$Electromagnetic$ $induction$ will take place in any $loop$( $conducting$ or $non-conducting$ ). That is because, the rate of change $magnetic$ $flux$ ($ -\frac{\mathrm{d} }{\mathrm{d} t}\iint_{ }^{ } \vec{B}.\vec{dA}$) creates an electric field in $space$. In the presence of a conducting loop, the electric field created will drive the electrons thereby giving rise to an induced current. In case of an insulator, polarization phenomenon will take place.